# Deploying create-react-app with webpack to heroku. Error in Loader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, create-react-app

Looks like that the app was deployed :

```
> Counting objects: 7, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done. Writing objects: 100% (7/7),
> 630 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
> remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source:
> remote:  remote: -----> Node.js app detected remote:  remote: ----->
> Creating runtime environment remote:         remote:       
> NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
> remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false remote:        NODE_ENV=production
> remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true remote:  remote: ----->
> Installing binaries remote:        engines.node (package.json): 
> unspecified remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified
> (use default) remote:         remote:        Resolving node version
> 6.x via semver.io... remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.10.2... remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.10 remote:  remote: -----> Restoring cache remote:        Loading 2 from
> cacheDirectories (default): remote:        - node_modules remote:     
> - bower_components (not cached - skipping) remote:  remote: -----> Building dependencies remote:        Installing node modules
> (package.json) remote:  remote: -----> Caching build remote:       
> Clearing previous node cache remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories
> (default): remote:        - node_modules remote:        -
> bower_components (nothing to cache) remote:  remote: -----> Build
> succeeded! remote: -----> Discovering process types remote:       
> Procfile declares types     -> (none) remote:        Default types for
> buildpack -> web remote:  remote: -----> Compressing... remote:       
> Done: 47.8M remote: -----> Launching... remote:        Released v19
> remote:        https://dry-depths-33506.herokuapp.com/ deployed to
> Heroku remote:  remote: Verifying deploy... done. To
> https://git.heroku.com/dry-depths-33506.git    1f1dcd3..40032c0 
> master -> master
```

But then I receive this:

Error in Loader /app/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js didn't return a function
     @ multi main

Comment: I guess this is just a UI and not a nodejs app. You have to run `npm build` or `yarn build` and then push only the generated `build` folder to heroku. The app will be detected as static app and apache will be used to server.

Comment: the app has a build folder, it was started as "create react app" but hen I've ejected it and added server folder with 2 files (Not sure if that can be a problem).  It also works with mongoDB, I've added mLabs in Heroku